# Can I use a FIFO for SourceReader?

Tags: c#, directx-11, ms-media-foundation, directx-9, sharpdx

I am trying to follow what the author did in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44847276/mediafoundation-cant-decode-video-on-certain-nvidia-cards), but I would like to decode nal units from a FIFO or pipe, so that I can enqueue nal units in to buffer from a producer thread (basycally a thread that receives nal units from different network protocols) and consume them with Media Foundation in another thread to decode them.

By studying the documentation, I understood that I must user a SourceReader to decode the video, but I am not able to find an example that does it by reading from a fifo or pipe.

How can I do it? It there any example that I can study?

Comment: FIFO/pipe are generic Algorithm/Api. You have to learn about this, and then apply to Mediafoundation.